# iText: button resize affects label

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to resize an existing PDF button.  I want to amend the label from "Print" to "Print Amended".

```
PushbuttonField button = form.getNewPushbuttonFromField("HoldButton");
Rectangle box = button.getBox();
box.setRight(box.getRight() + 72);  // Increase width by 1"
button.setBox(box);
button.setText("Print Amended");
form.replacePushbuttonField("HoldButton", button.getField());
```

The above code successfully changes the label, but not the size.  The end result is a button with no change in width, and the label "Print Amended" squished together.

Is it possible to resize an existing button in iText?

Comment: FYI: the change to was made to solve your problem has now been released: http://itextpdf.com/changelog/554

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your example and I was surprised that I could reproduce your problem.

I looked into the iText code and I see that it is explicitly forbidden to change the `/T` value. This makes sense: if you want to replace an existing button, you don't want to change its name.

However, for some reason we also explicitly forbid changing the `/Rect` value. See the code of the `AcroFields` class:

```
for (Object element : button.getKeys()) {
    PdfName key = (PdfName)element;
    if (key.equals(PdfName.T) || key.equals(PdfName.RECT))
        continue;
    if (key.equals(PdfName.FF))
        values.put(key, button.get(key));
    else
        widgets.put(key, button.get(key));
    merged.put(key, button.get(key));
    markUsed(values);
    markUsed(widgets);
}
```

I am not sure why we made this decision when we wrote this code. If I remove `|| key.equals(PdfName.RECT)`, then your code works as expected.

As we deliberately excluded changing the dimensions of the button, I am in doubt if this is a bug or if we intentionally added that code there. Reading your requirement, I am inclined to remove `|| key.equals(PdfName.RECT)` from the official source code.

**PS:** I know that this doesn't answer your question, but it does explain why your code doesn't work in spite of the fact that it looks perfectly OK. As I explained: I'm really surprised that it doesn't work, because I'm responsible for the iText code...

**PS 2:** I've changed the code in the official [trunk](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/6603/).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
newButton1 = new JButton("Print Amended") {
            {
                setSize(150, 75);
                setMaximumSize(getSize());
            }
        };
```

or:

Try to use `setMaximumSize()` method

```
button.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the button I'm dealing with is an iText PushbuttonField object.

Comment: Im sure you can still use the setMaximumSize() no?